# ¿De qué manera puedo realizar este diesño en HTML5?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me refiero a esas pequeñas líneas verticales.
Qué etiquetas son útiles para lograr esto y cómo estaría estructurado.

Gracias por leer

Comment: Estuve viendo el diseño cómo si se tratase de una tabla, pero cómo se realizarían las pequeñas líneas verticales?

Comment: ¿Ya has intentado algo? Aquí se valora el esfuerzo propio a la hora de colaborar con la pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Gracias, ya tengo algo pero pensé que eso era suficiente para resolver la duda, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima amigo.

Comment: Esto se puede hacer de muchas maneras diferentes. Deberías incluir qué es lo que has investigado e intentado y con qué problemas te estás encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de que a tu pregunta le falta un poco más de información para estar bien construida te ayudaré por que veo que no tienes alguna idea inicial de como empezar, acá te dejo una posible solución:

```css
#listado .item{
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: -2px;
  position: relative;
}

#listado .item:first-child{
  margin-left: 0;
}

#listado .item .info{
  text-align:center;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 23px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  background: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#listado .item .linea{
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="listado">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">1</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">2</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">3</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">4</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">5</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">6</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">7</div>
    <div class="linea"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Con mucho respeto a la respuesta dada, que es muy valida, yo sugeriría esta estructura:

```
<ul class="listado">
 <li data_number="1"></li>
 <li data_number="2"></li>
 <li data_number="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Ya que el resto elementos se pueden generar vía **`CSS`**, ya que tanto el numero y la linea de abajo se podría generar con seudoelementos, así:

```css
.listado{
  border: solid 1px #008b29;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listado li{
  position: relative;
  border: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
}

.listado li::before{
  display: block;
  content: attr(data_number);
  width: 20px;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #e6f2eb;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  border-bottom-width:2px;
  margin: auto;
}

.listado li::after{
  content: '';
  border: inherit;
  border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listado">
 <li data_number="1"></li>
 <li data_number="2"></li>
 <li data_number="3"></li>
 <li data_number="4"></li>
 <li data_number="5"></li>
 <li data_number="6"></li>
 <li data_number="7"></li>
 <li data_number="8"></li>
</ul>
```

Incluso si no necesitas colocar los números a mano, puedes generarlos via css y simplificar aún más el código, ejemplo:

```
<ul class="listado">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Y en el **`CSS`**, basta con poner:

```
.listado { counter-reset: nombre_x; }
.listado li{ counter-increment: nombre_x; } /*para contar los li*/
.listado li::before{ content: counter(nombre_x) ; }
```

Un ejemplo en vivo:

```css
.listado{
  border: solid 1px #008b29;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: numbers;
}

.listado li{
  position: relative;
  border: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  counter-increment: numbers;
}

.listado li::before{
  content: counter(numbers);
  display: block;
  width: 1.2em;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background: #e6f2eb;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  border-bottom-width:2px;
  margin: auto;
}

.listado li::after{
  content: '';
  border: inherit;
  border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
  height: 0.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listado">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```